# SSAS Calculated member that knows if the user is using the report filter

Tags: excel, pivot, ssas, mdx

I am trying to write a calculated member which acts differently depending on whether the user is filtering by that member or has it dragged down as rows or columns on their pivot table (using Excel).

The rules are:
1. If the user is using the date dimensin as a Report Filter in Excel, then the calculated member should get the maximum date out of all dates that they are filtered by.
2. If they have the date dimension as rows on the pivot table, then I need to apply ClosingPeriod and some other logic.

Comment: SSAS Tabular (DAX) or SSAS Multidimensional (MDX)? Or is this just excel pivot tables? Are you connecting to a cube? I guess for a calculated member this must be SSAS Multidimensional

Comment: Ssas multi dimensional cube

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. The idea came from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170226000233/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/08/25/mdx-in-katmai-dynamic-named-sets.aspx).

Basically the dynamic named set represents what's in the report filters. And the `EXISTING` keyword trims the list of days down to the filter context of the current cell letting you detect say if one month is on rows. Compare counts and you can detect what the user did.

```
CREATE HIDDEN DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.SelectedDays as
[Date].[Date].[Date].Members;

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[My Calc] as
CASE
 WHEN SelectedDays.Count > {existing [Date].[Date].[Date].Members}.Count
  THEN Tail({existing [Date].[Date].[Date].Members},1).Item(0).Item(0).Name
 WHEN SelectedDays.Count < [Date].[Date].[Date].Members.Count
  THEN Tail(SelectedDays,1).Item(0).Item(0).Name
END
```

Performance is going to not be good. And I suspect users will be confused with the results of your calc. If you want to describe the business scenario more I can maybe recommend a better approach.